# Making responsive viewport and @media work on Windows Server

Tags: responsive-design, windows-server-2008, viewport

I'm building a site in ASP.Net which has a responsive layout using the following:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1"/>`

on the aspx page, and in my styles.css using

```
@media screen and (min-width: 319px) {
#divname {color:#808080}
}
```

This is all working great when I test the site locally when I use "Start Debugging". However, when I upload the site to my Windows 2008 R2 server with IIS7 all browsers do not respond to the viewport size, and styles inside the `@media screen...` are ignored.

Is there something special I need to make this work on my server?

Answer (score 0):

My first suspicion is that it's something unrelated to your server.

- Doublecheck that there isn't a caching issue with any old files
- Make sure your browser hasn't cached old files
- Use devtools and check you don't have any 404s
- Check you don't have any CSS errors: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was removing my site from my IE Browser Compatibility View.